# Integral of cosine over a quadratic

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need help with the following integral:

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\cos\left(\, ax\,\right) \over 1-bx^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
$$

The constants $a$ and $b$ are both real and positive.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: My intuition tells me that this is not anti-differentiable.

Comment: oh the result looks ugly

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner ...does that imply you have a result? :P

Comment: yes i have asked my PC and he has found something

Comment: see herehttp://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/CalculusIntegralTableOfIntegrals.aspx

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks, that link quite useful. However, I don't believe my integral is on that list?

Comment: but it is on my PC!

Comment: for large enough b the integral is not even defined

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\cos\pars{ax} \over 1 - bx^{2}}\,\dd x}
=\half\bracks{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\cos\pars{ax} \over 1 - b^{1/2}x}\,\dd x
+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\cos\pars{ax} \over 1 + b^{1/2}x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm]&=\half\sum_{\sigma\ =\ \pm}\ 
\overbrace{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\cos\pars{ax} \over 1 + \sigma b^{1/2}x}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{1 + \sigma b^{1/2}x\equiv t\ \imp\
x = \sigma b^{-1/2}\pars{t - 1}}}}
\\[5mm]&=\half\sum_{\sigma\ =\ \pm}
\int_{1 - \sigma b^{1/2}\pi}^{1 + \sigma b^{1/2}\pi}
{\cos\pars{\sigma ab^{-1/2}t - \sigma ab^{-1/2}} \over t}\,\sigma b^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&={b^{-1/2}\cos\pars{ab^{-1/2}} \over 2}\sum_{\sigma\ =\ \pm}\sigma
\int_{1 - \sigma b^{1/2}\pi}^{1 + \sigma b^{1/2}\pi}
{\cos\pars{ab^{-1/2}t} \over t}\,\dd t
\\&+{b^{-1/2}\sin\pars{ab^{-1/2}} \over 2}\sum_{\sigma\ =\ \pm}\sigma
\int_{1 - \sigma b^{1/2}\pi}^{1 + \sigma b^{1/2}\pi}
{\sin\pars{ab^{-1/2}t} \over t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&={b^{-1/2}\cos\pars{ab^{-1/2}} \over 2}\sum_{\sigma\ =\ \pm}\sigma
\int_{ab^{-1/2} - \sigma a\pi}^{ab^{-1/2} + \sigma a\pi}
{\cos\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t
\\&+{b^{-1/2}\sin\pars{ab^{-1/2}} \over 2}\sum_{\sigma\ =\ \pm}\sigma
\int_{ab^{-1/2} - \sigma a\pi}^{ab^{-1/2} + \sigma a\pi}
{\sin\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t
\end{align}

> However,
>   \begin{align}
> \int_{\mu}^{\nu}{\cos\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t
> &=-\int_{\nu}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t
> -\bracks{-\int_{\mu}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t}
> ={\rm Ci}\pars{\nu} - {\rm Ci}\pars{\mu} 
> \\[5mm]
> \int_{\mu}^{\nu}{\cos\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t
> &=\int_{0}^{\nu}{\sin\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t
> -\int_{0}^{\mu}{\sin\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t
> ={\rm Si}\pars{\nu} - {\rm Si}\pars{\mu} 
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\rm Ci}$ and $\ds{\rm Si}$ are the
>   [Cosine Integral and the Sine Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral) , respectively.

Then,
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\cos\pars{ax} \over 1 - bx^{2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large b^{-1/2}\cos\pars{ab^{-1/2}}\braces{%
{\rm Ci}\pars{a\bracks{b^{-1/2} + \pi}} - {\rm Ci}\pars{a\bracks{b^{-1/2} - \pi}}}}
\\&\color{#66f}{\large \mbox{}+b^{-1/2}\sin\pars{ab^{-1/2}}\braces{%
{\rm Si}\pars{a\bracks{b^{-1/2} + \pi}} - {\rm Si}\pars{a\bracks{b^{-1/2} - \pi}}}}
\end{align}